# How to override CakePHP 2 paginate limit?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.x

I do really could not modify the query into the model, as an alternate i do create a new array `$dataNewResult` and push data into it, inside the controller data results `foreach` loop.

How can i override the limit property from the paginate object to match the new array count ?

I am trying :

```
$this->paginate['limit'] = $dataNewResult;
```

And i am getting this error message:
Indirect modification of overloaded property `MyobjectController::$paginate` has no effect

This is the code i am trying:

```
 if(base64_decode($this->passedArgs['Myobject.restriction']) == '0')
    {
        $this->set('data', $dataNewResult);
        $this->paginate['limit'] = count($dataNewResult);
    } else {
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an initial value to the property.  Set `$this->paginate = array();` before you set the limit.

```
$this->paginate = array();
$this->paginate['limit'] = count($dataNewResult);
```

Or declare the property in the controller class.

```
public $paginate = array();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters